# RubyTutorial 10.5.2 Rspec test micropost pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

While going through the Learn Rails book written by Michael Hartl, I'm stumped on one of the exercises.
[Learn Rails by Example by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts)

"Add tests for micropost pagination"

My incorrect test, placed in the 'describe "for signed-in users" do' is as follow:

```
describe "pagination" do
    before(:all) do 
      30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user) }
    end
    after(:all) { user.feed.delete_all }
    page.should have_selector('div.pagination') }

    it "should list each micropost" do
      user.feed.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
        page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end
    end
  end
```

The test shows as passed no matter if I do page.should or page.should_not.

Any 'hint/help' would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While browsing through some of the repos I found the answer to my question - I needed to visit the root_path again, after creating the additional microposts.

```
describe "pagination" do
  it "should paginate the feed" do
    30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Consectetur adipiscing elit") }
    visit root_path
    page.should have_selector("div.pagination")
  end
end
```

Comment: This helped me figure out pagination tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put an after all filter to do the clean-up to the mass insertions of the microposts; as your implementation stands (unless you do it in another part of your test code not shown here) it does not delete the created microposts.

This can be easily done through the following code:

```
describe "pagination" do
  after(:all) { user.microposts.delete_all unless user.microposts.nil? }
  it "should paginate the feed" do
     40.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user) }
     visit root_path
     page.should have_selector('div.pagination')
  end
end
```